# How can I avoid seeing the inside faces of a semitransparent object in the game engine?

Tags: game-engine, node-editor, transparency, shaders

I want to know if it's possible to make an object transparent just based on how the object is rendered when it's not transparent. I want this to avoid seeing the faces inside or on the other side of the object.

This is what I'm currently getting:
[image]

This is what I want to be able to do (done with post editing):
[image]

Comment: Try the *Geometry* node front/back output socket for filtering the face transparency, if you are using node materials

Comment: I don't think the problem here is that the backfaces are showing, it is the frontfaces inside/behind the object that is normally obscured when the object is not transparent. Example project: [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-FsXUCTbguSRHJXX1VSa0Q5MzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yeah, your are right, I mean some of them are, but the viewport seems to get confused about it somehow. Anyway it would do about the same as *Backface culling*, never mind

Answer (score 1):

In the material editor (cycles) add a geometry node and look at the "Backfacing" output. Plug it into the fac of a new mix shader where one input is what you already have and the other is a completely white Transparent shader. You haven't uploaded a .blend file so I can't know what  exactly you are doing but I hope this helps.

Comment: The user is specifically using the Blender Game Engine, not Cycles